# Can't extend main partition to use free space

Tags: windows-10

How can I extend the C partition so that it uses the "Free space" partition?

The extend option is greyed out when right clicking the C partition:

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: Delete the extended partition the you will be able to extend your other partition into the unallocated partition

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ramhound has already solved the problem, I'll just elaborate a bit here.

Under BIOS (non UEFI), it is possible to have only a limited number of physical partitions (say n). As a result, to have more that that many partitions, you create n-1 physical and 1 extended partition. Now you cannot use this partition directly, but you can create several logical partitions inside this. However, if there is free space inside the extended partition, it belongs to that partition and hence cannot be accessed from outside. Thus, while you have supposedly free unpartitioned space, the disc actually sees it as a separate unformatted partition.

Now, if you delete this extended partition, then the OS correctly recognises the available empty space as unallocated, and hence you can extend the partition before it, which was earlier not possible.